# Google Now confused about my texts

Tags: sms, google-now

I know that the last SMS I received was spam from the local pizza takeout; before that was a message from Joe.

If I ask "Ok Google; read my last text" it replies that "You have one last text message; it's from Joe. Do you want to hear it?", and shows the last message from Joe - which is not the last message overall.

If I ask "Ok Google; read my last text from Joe" it replies "I couldn't find any."

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: If you need device or version information, please just ask. While I'm experienced with tech problems and support in general, I'm new to this specific SE site.